# Picocli: Is it possible to define options with a space in the name?

Tags: java, command-line-arguments, picocli

I googled around for a bit and also searched on StackOverflow and of course the Picocli docs but didn't come to any solution.

The company I work at uses a special format for command line parameters in batch programs:

```
-VAR ARGUMENT1=VALUE -VAR ARGUMENT2=VALUE2 -VAR BOOLEANARG=FALSE
```

(Don't ask me why this format is used, I already questioned it and didn't get a proper answer.)
Now I wanted to use Picocli for command line parsing. However, I can't get it to work with the parameter format we use, because the space makes Picocli think those are two separate arguments and thus it won't recognise them as the ones I defined.

This won't work, obviously:

```
@CommandLine.Option( names = { "-VAR BOOLEANARG" } )
boolean booleanarg = true;
```

Calling the program with -VAR BOOLEANARG=FALSE won't have any effect.

Is there any way to custom define those special option names containing spaces? Or how would I go about it? I also am not allowed to collapse multiple arguments as parameters into one -VAR option.

Help is much appreciated. 
Thanks and best regards,
Rosa

Comment: Yes this is possible by defining the `-VAR` option as a `Map` (https://picocli.info/#_maps).

Comment: I provided a more detailed answer below. I hope it meets your requirements. Enjoy picocli! :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Solution 1: Map Option

The simplest solution is to make `-VAR` a [Map option](https://picocli.info/#_maps). That could look something like this:

```java
@Command(separator = " ")
class Simple implements Runnable {

    enum MyOption {ARGUMENT1, OTHERARG, BOOLEANARG}

    @Option(names = "-VAR",
            description = "Variable options. Valid keys: ${COMPLETION-CANDIDATES}.")
    Map<MyOption, String> options;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // business logic here
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CommandLine(new Simple()).execute(args);
    }
}
```

The usage help for this example would look like this:

```
Usage: <main class> [-VAR <MyOption=String>]...
      -VAR <MyOption=String>
         Variable options. Valid keys: ARGUMENT1, OTHERARG, BOOLEANARG.
```

Note that with this solution all values would have the same type (`String` in this example), and you may need to convert to the desired type (`boolean`, `int`, other...) in the application.

However, this may not be acceptable given this sentence in your post:

> I also am not allowed to collapse multiple arguments as parameters into one -VAR option.

## Solution 2: Argument Groups

One idea for an alternative is to use [argument groups](https://picocli.info/#_argument_groups): we can make `ARGUMENT1`, `OTHERARG`, and `BOOLEANARG` separate options, and put them in a group so that they *must* be preceded by the `-VAR` option.

The resulting usage help looks something like this:

```
Usage: group-demo [-VAR (ARGUMENT1=<arg1> | OTHERARG=<otherValue> |
                  BOOLEANARG=<bool>)]... [-hV]
      -VAR                   Option prefix. Must be followed by one of
                               ARGUMENT1, OTHERARG or BOOLEANARG
      ARGUMENT1=<arg1>       An arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.
      OTHERARG=<otherValue>  Another arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.
      BOOLEANARG=<bool>      A boolean arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.
  -h, --help                 Show this help message and exit.
  -V, --version              Print version information and exit.
```

And the implementation could look something like this:

```java
@Command(name = "group-demo", mixinStandardHelpOptions = true,
        sortOptions = false)
class UsingGroups implements Runnable {

    static class MyGroup {
        @Option(names = "-VAR", required = true,
          description = "Option prefix. Must be followed by one of ARGUMENT1, OTHERARG or BOOLEANARG")
        boolean ignored;

        static class InnerGroup {
            @Option(names = "ARGUMENT1", description = "An arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.")
            String arg1;

            @Option(names = "OTHERARG", description = "Another arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.")
            String otherValue;

            @Option(names = "BOOLEANARG", arity = "1",
              description = "A boolean arg. Must be preceded by -VAR.")
            Boolean bool;
        }

        // exclusive: only one of these options can follow a -VAR option
        // multiplicity=1: InnerGroup must occur once
        @ArgGroup(multiplicity = "1", exclusive = true)
        InnerGroup inner;
    }


    // non-exclusive means co-occurring, so if -VAR is specified,
    // then it must be followed by one of the InnerGroup options
    @ArgGroup(multiplicity = "0..*", exclusive = false)
    List<MyGroup> groupOccurrences;

    @Override
    public void run() {
        // business logic here

        System.out.printf("You specified %d -VAR options.%n", groupOccurrences.size());
        for (MyGroup group : groupOccurrences) {
            System.out.printf("ARGUMENT1=%s, ARGUMENT2=%s, BOOLEANARG=%s%n",
                    group.inner.arg1, group.inner.arg2, group.inner.arg3);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new CommandLine(new UsingGroups()).execute(args);
    }
}
```

Then, invoking with `java UsingGroups -VAR ARGUMENT1=abc -VAR BOOLEANARG=true` gives:

```
You specified 2 -VAR options.
ARGUMENT1=abc, OTHERARG=null, BOOLEANARG=null
ARGUMENT1=null, OTHERARG=null, BOOLEANARG=true
```

With this approach, you will get a `MyGroup` object for every time the end user specifies `-VAR`. This `MyGroup` object has an `InnerGroup` which has many fields, *all but one* of which will be `null`. Only the field that the user specified will be non-`null`. That is the disadvantage of this approach: in the application you would need to inspect all fields to find the non-`null` one that the user specified. The benefit is that by selecting the right type for the `@Option`-annotated field, the values will be automatically converted to the destination type.

Comment: @rosa Was this answer useful for you? Let me know if you have more questions. Otherwise, can you Accept this answer?

Comment: Hi Remko! Sorry for replying late. I was super busy the last couple of days. Thanks a lot for your reply! I will try this and then accept your answer if it works for me.

Comment: Hi Rosa, thanks for getting back. Understood. No worries! Don’t hesitate to ask questions if there’s anything unclear. Enjoy picocli! :-)

Comment: Hi Remko, thanks for pointing me into the direction of Maps and Groups! I've played around for a bit and tried both. I have a couple of questions. When using the Maps option, do I have to implement a custom type converter, as the arguments can have different types? String, boolean, Date and so on. And then assign the appropriate type in the custom converter? But then I would be reinventing the wheel - is there a better way? And for the Group option: How do I ever know for sure which argument is in which place in the list? I think I have to take a bit more time to explore this a bit further.

Comment: With the Map converter, all values end up as `String`, and the application would need to convert to the desired type. That is a drawback of the simplicity. With the Group approach, you will get a `MyGroup` object for every time the end user specifies `-VAR`. This `MyGroup` object has an `InnerGroup` which has many fields, _all but one_ of which will be `null`. Only the field that the user specified will be non-`null`. So in the application you would need to inspect all fields to find the non-`null` one that the user specified.

Comment: Hmm okay that's what I reckoned / observed in my tests. Ok, so I suppose there is no truly elegant way of solving this issue. But I will figure out something that works for me with your approaches.  Thanks a lot, I will accept your answer!